# How to debug variables in a C++ class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class square{
public:
    int side;
    square(int);
    void operator==( square);


};
square::square( int s){
    s=0;
}
void square::operator==(square s1){
    if (side == s1.side){

        cout<<"True"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"False"<<endl;

}

int main(){
    square sq1(10);
    square sq2(20);
    square sq3(20);
    sq1.operator==(sq2);
    sq2.operator==(sq3);




}
```

The output is printing false when its comparing sq3 and sq2 although it should print True because they both have the same value, any help?

Comment: Why the constructor of squre set the parameter to 0 ?

Comment: what do you intend to do with `s=0;` in your constructor?

Comment: You never set `side` to anything.

Comment: Just printing the values would have shown something suspicious. You haven't exactly killed yourself while trying to debug this...

Comment: The point of overloading operators is that it allows you to use those operators in the normal manner; `sq1 == sq2`. (And the equality operator should return a `bool`, not print anything; `return side == s1.side;`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor seems incoherent with what you expect it to do. It should be this :

```
square::square( int s){
    side = s;
}
```

Comment: lmao thanks, still new to this and I am already feeling super dumb

Comment: @ahrnad No need to feel dumb, but do get yourself a good book. I recommend Professional C++ (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-C-Marc-Gregoire/dp/1118858050)

Answer (score 3):

I have tidied up your code

- The comparison operator (operator==) should have this signature
  `bool T::operator ==(const T2 &b) const;`
- You constructor did not set the member variable
- I added a default value for the constructor so `side` always has a known value.
- You do not need to explicitly call `operator==`. You can simply use `==` and the compiler will use the best match.
- For this case, you *could* get away with just a `operator int` conversion method and still call `sq1 == sq2`. I added one but commented it out, Try it and see which one the compiler will pick.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  class square
  {
    int side;
  public:
    square(int s = 0) : side(s){}
    // operator int() { return side; }
    // OR  (for this use case)
    bool operator==( const square& that ){ return ( that.side == this->side ); }
  };

  int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
  {
    square sq1(10);
    square sq2(20);
    square sq3(20);
    // cout << (sq1.operator==(sq2)?"true":"false");
    // cout << (sq2.operator==(sq3)?"true":"false");
    // No need to explicitly call operator==, the comparison is inferred
    cout << (sq1 == sq2 ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << (sq2 == sq3 ? "true" : "false") << endl;;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor should initialize the variable int size in your class. What you did in your constructor is set the value of the argument to zero, not the side itself in your class. So it should be like these:

```js
square::square(int s)
{
    side = s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They *don't* both have the same value.

They both have an unspecified value, because you never initialised or assigned to `side`.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think it's because you have answered a lazy question (where "lazy" means it shows no debugging effort), which for some is a valid reason for downvoting. I have also been bitten by this. Besides, the first 3 comments had already found the problem, and there were already 2 answers when you posted yours, and the OP had already said "thank you" to one of them, which he then accepted. Late answers that don't add anything new are not welcome. In these cases I don't downvote, but I don't upvote either, even though the answer is correct (which indeed it is).

Comment: And of course your rep is *very* high, so all of this shouldn't be news to you. To be honest I was surprised to see your answer, given all of this.

Comment: @FabioTurati: Answers do not go in the comments section. When the answer is only found in the comments section, I _absolutely will_ write an answer. If the comment-writers are upset about this, they should have written their answer in the correct place. And the only answer other than mine which _actually identifies the issue_ was posted _after mine_. So, in conclusion, my answer was the first to actually answer the question. If that's not "adding something new", then what is? Downvoting on that basis is ridiculous.

Comment: @FabioTurati: Also, defending your argument on the basis of "you should know better" assumes that you are actually right, which is kind of condescending... especially when there's grounds to disagree with you (as explored above). Thanks.

Comment: We seem to disagree on the value of Pierre's and LinkedRom's answers. True, they don't mention that the error is due to uninitialised variables, which you pointed out. But you stopped there. If there was only your answer, the OP could wonder *why* they are uninitialised, which is explained by the others: the constructor is wrong. Your approach is more didactical, showing him which way to investigate; theirs is more practical, giving the full solution. When I said you haven't added anything I meant that if the OP understands their solution, he can also deduce the rest. Just that, no offense.

Comment: And while we are at it... Let me add that I was by no means trying to attack you. I was just trying to provide an explanation of why you got downvoted, since it seemed clear to me but you sounded surprised. And when I mentioned your rep and said you should know this, I didn't mean that you shouldn't have posted your answer (though *I* wouldn't have done it); I simply meant that you could have expected some negative feedback, and in case understood the reason. I realise my sentence sounds more aggressive (or, as you say, condescending) than I wanted, and I apologise for that.